# Extracting Partial Text (before the <br>) using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname, outerhtml

I'm having trouble grabbing the specific piece of text out of the Class attribute. The text has both a name and an ID. Both are important to me, but I need them split and placed in separate arrays.

```
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name1</b><br> ID1</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name2</b><br>ID2</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name3</b><br> ID3</span>
```

My first thought was to pop off the last item in each element (convert to string or list, delimit by a " " and pop off the last item). But, I realized that there is not always a space between the Name and ID so that doesn't work.

My second thought was to use the OuterHTML and grab everything before the `<br>` then do the same with the ID after the `<br>`.

However, this is what the returned text looks like which using outerHTML:

```
"&lt;span class=\&quot;locDescription\&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Name1&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;ID1&lt;/span&gt;"
```

I could not find a way to simply grab before the `<br>`... that would seem like something one could do easily... maybe I'm missing it.

In lieu of that, I attempted to use indexing to grab the text:

```
var product_name = []
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('locDescription');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) product_name.push(elements[i].outerHTML)

test1 = product_name[0].indexOf('&gt;&lt;b&gt;')

console.log(test1)
```

That came back as -1 so it's not interpreting the garble in that text. Any idea of how I can accomplish this? I think I'm going down a rabbit hole at the moment.

Comment: `const bs = document.querySelectorAll('.locDescription>b'); for(let b of bs){ console.log(b.textContent); }`

Comment: Seems like you forgot the 'R' of "br" in your `.indexOf()`: `'&gt;&lt;b&gt;'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

querySelector and childNodes

```js
const spans = [...document.querySelectorAll(".locDescription")];
const details = spans.map(span => {
  const name = span.querySelector("b").textContent;
  const id = span.childNodes[2].nodeValue;
  return { name, id };
});
console.log(details);
```

```html
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name1</b><br> ID1</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name2</b><br>ID2</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name3</b><br> ID3</span>
```

```js
const spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".locDescription"));
const details = spans.map(function(span){
  const name = span.querySelector("b").textContent;
  const id = span.childNodes[2].nodeValue;
  return { name: name, id: id };
});
console.log(details);
```

```html
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name1</b><br> ID1</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name2</b><br>ID2</span>
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name3</b><br> ID3</span>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Unfortunately, GTM doesn't allow the use of Spread or arrow functions? Is it possible to achieve the same thing with a different method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the properties `.previousSibling` and `.nextSibling` of a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), those properties include other nodes, meaning [TextNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) as well.

**Note** that you might want to `trim()` the `.textContent` of those other Nodes you want, as `.textContent` returns the text how it is written in your HTML *after* escaping HTML-Name codes, that means including the white-spaces and line-breaks, if any.

Here is a quick example:

1. Query for `<br>`
2. Use `.previousSibling`/`.nextSibling`
3. Get their `.textContent`
4. (Optional) `trim()` the returned text

```js
var brElement = document.querySelector('br');

console.log(brElement.previousSibling.textContent.trim());
console.log(brElement.nextSibling.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<p><b>First text</b><br>
Second text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find the two sides:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("locDescription")[0];
var array = [];
array[0] = element.innerHTML.match(/.*(?=<br>)/)[0];
array[1] = element.innerHTML.match(/(?<=<br>).*/)[0];
console.log(array)
```

```html
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name1</b><br> ID1</span>
```

If you want to exclude the `<b>` tags:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("locDescription")[0];
var array = [];
array[0] = element.innerHTML.match(/(?<=<b>).*(?=<\/b>)/)[0]
array[1] = element.innerHTML.match(/(?<=<br>).*/)[0];
console.log(array)
```

```html
<span class="locDescription"><b>Name1</b><br> ID1</span>
```